# Hyperledger on iOS/Android mobile devices

Tags: android, ios, blockchain, hyperledger

As Docker is the underlying Chaincode deployment vessel, are there any workarounds that would enable the said mobile devices to act as nodes in the Hyperledger network? I realize HL IROHA is creating a library to solve the issue, but I could not find a tangible timeline for that, as it right now does not provide a full integration with a distributed ledger on IoT.

Comment: Iroha does not provide full integration with distributed ledger? Where is the user registered then if created using the demo app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About Iroha, there are two options depending on what you mean by iOS/Android device.

1. If we are speaking about ARM-based hardware with some linux onboard (like Raspberry PI) or rooted Android device, then it is possible to launch Iroha as a node (a peer within a network) on that device. In that case, Iroha will run as a platform-native binary.
2. If we are speaking about default iOS or Android device with untouched factory shell (GUI), then it is generally not possible and we are not providing any instructions regarding this. 
   Though you still can create mobile applications that use Iroha. They will be Iroha clients and would not serve as peers.

In order to run Iroha on ARM device you have to build it on the target platform. 
Building Iroha requires notable amount of RAM - for 32-bit ARM host you will need 8GB RAM.
The build can be performed inside Docker container. To prepare the container you will need to:

1. Clone Iroha git repo: https://github.com/hyperledger/iroha
2. Do docker build -t iroha-build-env . being in iroha/docker/develop
3. Run the newly built container and build there Iroha itself

Please do not forget to mount a folder with Iroha git repository to the container

Answer (score 0):

Android clients want to use bindings like any other people so we need to give them shared library for architectures like arm64-v8a and others. Bindings are NOT implementation of shared model, they are just a bridge between Python/Java/other languages and native library. Java bindings use library for Linux or Mac so they do not work for Android.

You can make nodes dedicated to every mobile app registered to the network unlike providing a connection to the existing node.